# Weird exception when debugging in visual studio 2010 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception

I am experiencing this error when I try to debug my program. it seems that it cannot even take in the argument I pass to main function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc!=4) std::cout<<wrong input";
    else{
       //other codes
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I put my breakpoint on the first line (main function line) and it gives me the following error:

```
'MESH.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Avan\Documents\NUS\Yr3_Sem2\CS3242\MESH\Debug\MESH.exe',       Symbols loaded.
'MESH.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MESH.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MESH.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MESH.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MESH.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
First-chance exception at 0x00318c67 in MESH.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
Unhandled exception at 0x00318c67 in MESH.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
First-chance exception at 0x00318c67 in MESH.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading     location 0x003a0000.
Unhandled exception at 0x00318c67 in MESH.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x003a0000.
The program '[4800] MESH.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
```

So I presume the error comes from when I passing down the input. 
I have set the command line input argument in the project->properties->debugging

the error keep pointing to a **chkstk.asm** file which I have no idea what is it.

```
; Find next lower page and probe
cs20:
    sub     eax, _PAGESIZE_         ; decrease by PAGESIZE
    **test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page.**
    jmp     short cs10

_chkstk endp

    end
```

The pointer keep pointing to the line indicated above with the **. Can anyone tell me what could have gone wrong?

Comment: What else is in your "other codes"? Specifically, is there a big-arse object or array that is blowing away your automatic variable space?

Answer (score 4):

Well, given it's complaining about a stack overflow, the *first* thing I'd be looking at is if you're trying to allocate a lot of stuff on the stack.

For example, if your `//other codes` contains something like:

```
int bigarray[9999999999];
```

then that would be a likely culprit.

I wouldn't be too worried about the fact that the error is coming from `chkstk.asm`, that's almost certainly some defensive code which is checking to see if you've blown out the stack (hence `chkstk` for `check stack`) and generating the first-chance exception.

Comment: +1 barring evidence of code that points otherwise, this is easily the most likely candidate issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did have a big array in my header file.